# How to Make a Dynamic Dropdown Menu disappear when the Screen Size Increases

Tags: jquery

So I have a dynamic site with a dropdown menu that should only appear when the screen width goes below a width of 768px. The button make the menu slide down doesn't appear until that is the case and the menu isn't visible either. Yet when I press the button and the menu is down and I then increase the screen width, the menu stays visible.

Here is the jquery I have used to make the menu slide down and up when the button is pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var menu = $("#MobileMenuHolder")

$('#menu-trigger').click(function(){

if (menu.is(":visible"))
{
menu.slideUp(400);
$(this).removeClass("open");
}
else
{
menu.slideDown(400);
$(this).addClass("open");
}
```

I have looked up several solutions but they make the whole thing not work. So how do I get it to disappear when I increase the screen width?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use `$(window).resize()`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var winW = $(window).width();
    if(winW <= 768){
        //Show the menu
    } else {
        //hide the menu
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS is prefered for such things than Jquery

```
<style>
  .open {visibility: hidden;}
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .open {visibility:visible;}
  }
</style>
```

I hope this will do it.

Just use appropriate class name instead of `open`